# Having problems making GRUB work

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

I have a laptop with Kubuntu 22.04 and 2 SSD: an NVME on which I installed Kubuntu and another 1TB SATA. I wanted to make it also run Windows10, so I created a partition on the 1TB SSD where I installed it. However, I cannot make GRUB work. The only way I can boot into Windows is by entering Boot menu manually and selecting Windows. I tried reinstalling Grub, and a 'grub' folder appeared in '/boot/', but it still doesn't work. After that, I installed Boot Repair and there is no 'fix' option, only 'Create a BootInfo summary' (which I chose to create that summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F5tX82ysbD/). I also tried booting Kubuntu from a live image and installing boot repair there, but it did not work.
Do you have any idea what could fix my GRUB?

Comment: I'm having a problem understanding your issue. So, you're saying you now have both Kubuntu and Windows. But to boot Windows you have to enter a boot menu, which you don't like. But Grub menu is a boot menu, so Grub works, doesn't it? Or do you mean the BIOS/UEFI boot menu, not the Grub one? Also, I couldn't grasp: is Windows installed on the same disk as Kubuntu, or on another one?

Comment: GRUB will only be able to boot both operating systems if they are both installed as UEFI. Or they can both be installed in BIOS/CSM/Legacy (not recommended). If one is UEFI and the other is legacy, GRUB will only boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Similar question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436555/grub-cannot-boot-windows-error-not-a-valid-root-device