# Ubuntu installed on master SSD hard,windows 10 on slave HDD, Error when I choose windows "not a valid root device" but from boot menu they working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

HP zpbook laptop,
Ubuntu 22.4 installed on master SSD hard drive,windows 10 on a slave HDD.
when I choose windows, it provides a message saying 'error: not a valid root device."
When I choose Ubuntu works fine.
Quoteing from [Grub cannot boot Windows: "error: not a valid root device"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436555/grub-cannot-boot-windows-error-not-a-valid-root-device)

> Peculiarity. There is one thing that happens that I think is rather odd. Let's discuss three situations:
> 1- When I turn my pc on, wait for grub to appear and select Windows, the error occurs.
> 2- When I turn my pc on, enter the boot menu and select 'UEFI - Windows Boot Manager', I do boot into Windows.
> 3- When I turn my pc on, enter the boot menu, select 'UEFI - Ubuntu' and then select Windows in grub, it also boots to Windows.

Adding to it, I disabled fast boot from bios then opened windows then get it back to fast boot , after that windows did some disk scan and solved the issue and works fine for several times but without changing anything I got the same issue
I tried solution mentioned at the link above by disabled fast boot from windows but didn't work
Also disabled Hibernation but the same
Tried update-grub and

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add this and save quit

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

then install os prober

```
sudo apt install os-prober
```

then finally

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Legacy support and secure boot disabled At bios

Comment: Fast Boot is an UEFI setting, should be off, must be off when making changes. And fast startup is  a Windows setting & must be off. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  HP 15-dw4047nr Windows 11 WiFi issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482797
HP Zbook 15 NVRAM locked, install issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555

Comment: i did auto fix yesterday but don't remember the output but didn't solve it https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/54SvPcz7Gb/

Comment: You show default boot entry as Ubuntu. If Windows always works from UEFI boot menu, then some issue with Windows like bitlocker or fast startup on. Or even a chkdsk needed. Grub only boots working Windows, so even things that work in Windows may prevent grub from booting it. It used to not work with Secure boot on, but my new Dell with Windows 11 and Secure boot does boot from grub. HP often is a bit more sensitive and wants a Windows boot entry, but you have that. And HP wants boot order changed in its UEFI setting menu, not efibootmgr that every other UEFI system works with.

Comment: solved by disable fast boot in bios , thanks